# Patching Function That Gets Imported In a Separate File

Tags: python, pytest, patch, pytest-mock

```
# a.py

from b import my_func

def do_something():
   my_func()

# b.py

from c import my_other_func # patch this while testing a.do_something()

def my_func():
  my_other_func()
```

I have a unit test for `do_something` and I need to mock out something that gets imported in another file where a function used in `do_something` is defined. I've tried patching it a number of ways, such as:
`mock.patch("a.b.my_other_func")`, `mock.patch("b.my_other_func")`, but it hasn't gotten the naming correct yet. How would you mock `my_other_func` in a test again `do_something` in this case? I could just patch `b.my_func` directly, but I was hoping to be able to use it as is but just mock the underlying db call (which is happening in the `my_other_func` method).

Answer (score 1):

The path in `patch` should always be the exact path of the function which should be patched. So in this case you want to patch `my_other_func` which is imported and  called in  `b.py`, so your unittest should look like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from a import do_something


@patch('b.my_other_func')
def test_do_something(mock_my_other_func):
    mock_my_other_func.return_value = <mock value>
    actual = do_something()
    assert <expected test value> == actual
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the name of the file is f and the name of the function is func. If f is in the path where the current file is located, you can insert the func similar to the following code:

```
from .f import func
```

Otherwise, you should write the path of the file with the function relative to the current file path.

It is necessary that the names of your functions and files do not be same as the built-in functions or modules that are in the program environment.